# Program crashing when compare 2 string from array

Tags: c++

I cut this part of my Student management homework, and when i compare 2 name, 1 from the input, 1 is what i want to search, it print out the result but crash immediately. Please help. I appreciate any respond, thank you

```
class Student
{
public:
    string name;
public:
    void input();
};
class list
{
private:
    Student ds[100];
    int count=0;
    int number,addnum=0;
    int total=number+addnum;
public:
    void input(int y);
    void find();
    friend class SinhVien;
};
void SinhVien::input()
{
    fflush(stdin);
    gotoXY(5,9);cout<<"name : ";
    cin>>name;
}
void list::input(int y)
{
    fflush(stdin);
    createBox(2,5,63,20,7);
    gotoXY(8,y-3);
    cout<<"add student\n";
    gotoXY(8,y-1);
    if (count==0)
    {
        cout<<"number of students : ";
        cin>>number;
        for(int i=1; i<=number; i++)
        {
            gotoXY(8,7);
            cout<<"student "<<i<<endl;
            ds[i].input();
            count++;
        }
    }
    else if(count>0)
    {
        cout<<"number of student : ";
        cin>>addnum;
        for(int i=1; i<=addnum; i++)
        {
            ds[i+count].input();
            count++;
        }
    }

}
void list::find()
{
    int count=0;
    string name1;
    gotoXY(10,51);
    cout<<"type name : ";
    cin>>name1;
    for(int i=0; i<total; i++)
    {
        string name2 =ds[i].name;
        if( name1.compare(name2) ==0)
        {
            cout<<"yes";
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        cout<<"not found";
}

int main()
{
    list a;
    a.input(1);
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    if (x==1)
        a.find();

}
```

Comment: Step 1. Learn how to use a debugger. Pinpoint which line the crash occurs on and check what values your variables and memory has. If you're still unsure how to fix it at that point **then** ask on SO

Comment: When `total = number+addnum` is evaluated, `number` has not yet been initialized, and contains random garbage. At this point, your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized object. Practically speaking, `total` also contains random garbage, and then the loop in `find()` overruns array bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int number,addnum=0;
int total=number+addnum;
```

You initialize `total` to `number+addnum`. But at that point, `number` has not been assigned a value. So the value that gets assigned to `total` is junk. When you use it to stop your loop, your loop can run too far and access the array out of bounds.